# Understanding the Steiner triple system

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

I am learning what Steiner systems are and I stumboled upon this Wolfram Mathworld source: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerTripleSystem.html.

I understand that $k = 3$ means that there are exactly 3 points(elements of set $X$) on each block. I also understand that the first parameter means how many points there are altogether. However I do not understand what is $\lambda$ that is the third parameter of $S$ in $S (v)=S(v,k=3,\lambda = 1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some of the parameters of a block design. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design):

- $v$ is the number of points (elements of $X$).
- $b$, not appearing in the article you're quoting, is the number of blocks: the subsets of $X$ we're taking.
- $r$, also not appearing in the article, is the number of blocks containing a given point.
- $k$ is the number of points in a block (for a Steiner **triple** system, $k=3$).
- $\lambda$ is the number of blocks containing...
- ...any $t$ distinct points. In the case of a Steiner triple system, $\lambda=1$ and $t=2$: for any two distinct points, there is exactly one subset containing them.

Comment: Actually my question is what does it mean "the number of blocks containing". Containing what exactly?

Comment: ...any $t$ distinct points. I've split that sentence across two bullet points because there's two parameters defined in it.